# FlatList onEndReached called On Load (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

When I use `onEndReached` function in `FlatList`, it gets called automatically.

Below is the link of this issue.

[Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16067)

Is there a solution available for it or any alternative in iOS?

**Edited:**

Below is the code I tried but this doesn't seems to work.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            flatListReady:false
        }
    }

    loadMore(){
        if(!this.state.flatListReady){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            alert("End Reached")
        }
    }

    _scrolled(){
        this.setState({flatListReady:true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                <FlatList
                    data={listData}
                    renderItem={({item}) => this._renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
                    onEndReached={() => this.loadMore()}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    onScroll={() => this._scrolled()}
                />

            </Layout>
```

Comment: It would be great if you can post the snippet what have you tried so far, which props did you passed and etc... and

Comment: @TrinadhKoya please check my updated question. :)

Comment: remove onScroll

Comment: And add braces {} around this.loadMore()

Comment: Gokul it still doesn't work.

Comment: renderItem={({item}) => this._renderItem(item)} 
to
renderItem={this._renderItem}
and then destruct inside renderItem

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is Layout is a View or ScrollView?

Comment: @TrinadhKoya it's a View

Comment: check out my answer mentioned below.

Comment: @TrinadhKoya `onEndReached` still gets called onLoad

Answer (score 14):

Try this,

```
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
if(distanceFromEnd >= 0) {
     //Call pagination function
}
}}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Anything inside onEndReached function gets called onLoad of component.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes things don't work like they are supposed to, at the end of the day it's not native code where, so may the order of your components or the fact that the `Flatlist` is encapsulated in a component that is not intended to be, or there is some property should be passed to the `Flatlist` component itself to activate the `onEndReached` callback properly.

I've faced this myself, and I didn't know what to do to make it work properly.

A beautiful workaround is derived from the fact the `Flatlist` inherits `ScorllView` properties. so you could use the `onScroll` property to detect if the end has reached or not.

```js
<FlatList
    data={this.props.dashboard.toPreviewComplaints}
    onScroll={({nativeEvent})=>{
        //console.log(nativeEvent);
        if(!this.scrollToEndNotified && this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)){
             this.scrollToEndNotified = true;
             this.loadMoreData();
        }
    }}
/>
```

> `this.scrollToEndNotified` is used as a flag not to abuse the call to the `loadMore` endpoint

```js
isCloseToBottom({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}){
    return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - 100;
}
```

So whenever it succeed in the `isCloseToBottom` call it means that you have reached the end of the list, so you can call the `loadMoreData` function

Answer (score -3):

**handle this function very carefully,**

```
  endReached=()=>{
          //take care of ES6 Fat arrow function and trigger your conditions properly with current state and new state data or current state with new Props.
    Based on those conditions only, you need to trigger the other API call

    }
```

---

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data}
     extraData={this.state.load}
     renderItem={this.renderCard}
     keyExtractor={item => item.fundRequestId}
     onEndReached={this.endReached}
     onEndReachedThreshold={.7}
     ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
     />
```